# Angular 2 and DatePipe milliseconds

Tags: angular

I have a google map where I click a unit. When I click a unit I get some data about the unit from a REST through a service. I then get StartToday witch is in seconds. I then want to show it as `HH:mm:ss`. My StartToday returns 360.

```
{{unit.StartToday * 1000}} // Works is 360000
{{360000 | date: "HH:mm:ss"}} // Works is 01:06:00
{{unit.StartToday * 1000 | date: "HH:mm:ss"}} // Does not work
```

But I get this error:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./MapComponent class MapComponent - inline template:11:12 caused by: Invalid argument 'NaN' for pipe 'DatePipe'
>   ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Invalid argument 'NaN' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
{{ (toNumber(unit.StartToday) * 1000) | date: "HH:mm:ss" }}
```

and make sure unit.StartToday is a number:

```
toNumber(input_to_number:any){
 return Number(input_to_number);
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ficVwQ2DO9E8jYpn4V4a?p=preview

Good Luck!

Comment: Are you sure unit.StartToday is a number?
what you see when you print :
`{{unit.StartToday}} ` ?

Comment: It shows 360. Also the value I can se on the rest url. Should I pass as integer? Or could the value not be ready when angular try to pipe it.